# How to maintain a session through the project in android?

Tags: android

**i have created session like this:**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("sessionmanagement",0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = settings.edit();
      editor2.putBoolean("flag",true);
      editor2.putString("user","usernamehere");
      editor2.commit();
```

Blockquote

and retriveing session data like this but i'm geeting null value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          String uname=sharedpreferences.getString("username", null);         
          TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);      
            tv2.setText(String.valueOf(uname));
```

**but getting null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your preferences:

```
getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

is no the same as?

```
getSharedPreferences("sessionmanagement",0);
```

Comment: Thank You very much..Finally I got it.I correct my mistake.thanks for help to get this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... you save the key "user", but read the key "username". The **keys differ**!
If you retrieve the key "user", you'll get the saved value for **that** key ("usernamehere", in your example).